Installing SPSS for Ubuntu
I'm stuck with my statistics duties because all alternatives to spss (lab/pspp/...) for Ubuntu are useless..
I need please any version if spss for Ubuntu 20.04

OK, so what is the question? Have you bought SPSS? Are you asking us for a free version of a non-free tool?

SPSS is proprietary software. You must ask the owner of the software. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSLVMB_26.0.0/pdf/en/Authorized_User_License_Installation_Instructions_Linux.pdf

According to their website, SPSS is available for Linux (of course you will have to buy a license). What is your question exactly?

Are you familiar with R ? https://www.r-project.org/ It is a free software for statistical computing available on the official Ubuntu repositories.

Along with R you may want to install R-Studio, a GUI interface for R. R-Studio is free for personal use.

SPSS Installation Instructions on Ubuntu

Download SPSS Statistics.

Extract the contents of the downloaded file.

Change to the directory where you extracted the files.

Make sure the permissions for setup.bin are set to execute.

At the command prompt, type: sudo ./setup.bin

Follow the instructions that appear in the installation program.


Open SPSS Statistics

Browse to the /opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/bin directory (23 is the SPSS version).

Run the stats file.


Create a desktop shortcut and add SPSS to the apps menu
Create ~/.local/share/applications/SPSS.desktop and add these lines to the file:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=SPSS
Exec= /opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/bin/stats
Icon=SPSS

Download any SPSS icon, rename it to SPSS, and add it to ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps, repeat this for /32x32/apps, etc. Log out and log in, you will see the SPSS icon in the apps menu.
Copy or create a link for ~/.local/share/applications/SPSS.desktop to ~/Desktop, right-click on ~/Desktop/SPSS.desktop, and allow launching.

SPSS Linux Installation Instructions (Authorized User License)
